# Insert into Access database using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ms-access

Right now I'm studying JavaScript for our next semester.

The problem is, I can't insert data in my database (MS Access). What is wrong or missing in the syntax?

Note: I also tried the `+` instead of `&`. Here is my code:

```
function register(){
    var fname = document.getElementById('fname').value;
    var lname = document.getElementById('lname').value;
    var usernn = document.getElementById('username').value;
    var passw = document.getElementById('password').value;

                    }

var con = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Connection");
var constring = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source = Z:\JavaScript Practice Code\jscript.accdb";
var rset = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Recordset");
       con.Open(constring);
function register(){

var sql = "Insert into register(fname,lname,usern,passw) Values('"&fname&"','"&lname&"','"&usernn&"','"&passw&"')";

rset.Open(sql, con);

con.Close();
rset.Close();
   }
```

Comment: `Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.12.0` is wrong. Try `Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0`.

Comment: Change it already to ACE. Still it cannot insert data :v

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ADODB.Recordset` objects are for retrieving rows via a `SELECT` statement. To execute an `INSERT` statement you should use an `ADODB.Command` object like this:

```js
var adVarWChar = 202;
var adParamInput = 1;

// test data
var fname = "Gord";
var lname = "Thompson";

var con = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Connection");
con.Open("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\\Users\\Public\\Database1.accdb");
var cmd = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Command");
cmd.ActiveConnection = con;
cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Employee (FirstName, LastName) VALUES (?, ?)";
cmd.Parameters.Append(cmd.CreateParameter("?", adVarWChar, adParamInput, 50, fname));
cmd.Parameters.Append(cmd.CreateParameter("?", adVarWChar, adParamInput, 50, lname));
cmd.Execute();
con.Close();
```

Comment: Sir in the commandtext values, how should i write the element names?
Values('"&fname&"')?

Comment: You just use the question mark (`?`) as the parameter placeholder in the VALUES clause, and then declare (.Append) the Parameters in the same order that they appear in the CommandText. I have updated the code to illustrate.

Comment: Sir I have one last question if you dont mind. In the line cmd.Parameters.Append, what is the use of number 50 and is "Gord" the element id of the variable? Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: 50 is the maximum length ("Size") for the parameter (i.e., 50 characters in this case since the fields were defined as `Text(50)`). "Gord" is the (literal) value to be inserted into the corresponding column. Details [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms677209%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: I have tweaked the code to clarify where the value of the parameter comes from.